# Sending data between classes in separate files

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm a new programmer and I'm trying to figure out how to send data between classes in separate files.  My goal is to take input from the user, and send it to another class.  The class then takes the `int input` to create and set the size of an array.  This is what I have:

**Main class:**

```
int size = input.nextInt();

    Thing thing = new Thing(size);
```

**Second class:**

```
public class Thing {

public static int[] Thing(int size) {
    int[] thing;
    thing = new int[size];

}
```

I would like to be able to have a useable array of size `size`, but I'm not sure about what I need to tackle this.  I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: You've already done it.  I don't understand the question.

Comment: This code looks right to me. What errors are you running into?

Comment: calling your method exactly the same as your class is bound to produce A LOT of problems. Please do not do that. Either create a constructor OR a regular method, but do not mix them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I'm not sure if you are going for a static implementation, or an object implementation. Here are both ways to approach it. Personally, I'd recommend the object approach.

You pretty much did it already. If you want a static method, I would suggest changing the name of your method and doing something like so:

```
public static int[] createThing(int size) {
    int[] thing;
    thing = new int[size];
    return thing; 
}
```

Then you would call it like:

```
int[] Thing = Thing.createThing(size);
```

If you are trying to do this as an object, you need to create a constructor, which will return a thing object, but you'll need change your `Thing` class to:

```
public class Thing {
int[] thingArray;

 public Thing(int size) {
    this.thingArray = new int[size];
 }
 public int[] getThingArray(){
    return this.thingArray; 
 }
}
```

then you would call:

```
Thing thing = new Thing(size);
```

to create a new `Thing` object, and to get the array from the object you do:

```
thing.getThingArray();
```

Comment: How so @luk2302 ? The OP is creating a new object, not calling a static method.

Comment: But then you cannot return a `int[]` if it is a constructor

Comment: Thanks for the update. And thanks for deleting the question in the meantime while correcting it.